# ASP .NET MVC ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I'm trying to make the (2) red and bold in the below code but it just displays the tag instead. I tried Html.Raw() but it returns IHtmlString that can't be used in ActionLink.

```
@{String surveyCount = "Survey &lt;b>(2)&lt;b>"; }
@Html.ActionLink(surveyCount, "Index", "Student")</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@{
 string surveyCount = 2;
 }

<a href="@Html.Action("Index","Student")">Survey <b>@surveyCount</b></a>
```

can be like this

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Student")">Survey <span class="danger">(2)</span></a>
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations.